# UIWebViewDelegate manual release in ARC?

Tags: ios

UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference states that:

> Before releasing an instance of UIWebView for which you have set a delegate, you must first set the UIWebView delegate property to nil before disposing of the UIWebView instance. This can be done, for example, in the dealloc method where you dispose of the UIWebView.

is it still necessary in ARC?

Comment: I definitely would (and do). Seems like there are two possible issues. One is the strong reference cycle (aka retain cycle) issue, which I don't think applies here. The second is that this object might be asynchronously calling the delegate methods from another queue. Perhaps not an issue, but given the warning of the docs, I'd be inclined to follow that advice of making sure to `nil` the delegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the delegate is defined as a WEAK property, nilling the delegate out is unnecessary as ARC will do this for you. However, if the class is not compiled with ARC and the delegate is marked with "assign", you must take care and set it to nil yourself.

Comment: I checked the source code of UIWebView. The delegate is defined as assign (not weak) even if I enabled ARC for my project. It looks like I have to handle it myself.

Comment: In what method would we set the delegate to nil?

Comment: @NicHubbard dealloc is the method

Comment: @Stavash And that is okay under ARC?

Comment: It's not not OK, it's just redundant.

Comment: @NicHubbard, it's fine to override dealloc with ARC. You just shouldn't call [super dealloc] in your overridden version.

Comment: Sadly `UIWebView`'s delegate has *not* been updated to be ARC friendly. It is still declared as `assign` not `weak`. (Insert sad face here). However `WKWebView` (iOS 8+) has it's delegates declared correctly. i.e. `weak`.

Comment: It's not just you ;-) [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342075/why-is-uiwebviewdelegate-assign-instead-of-weak/36342604)