# why is UIWebViewDelegate assign instead of weak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, automatic-ref-counting

Normally all delegates throughout the UIKit/Foundation frameworks are weak except UIWebView.

[UIWebView's delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate)

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id< UIWebViewDelegate > delegate;
```

I am interested because this has caused a crash several time in my application when you forgot to nil out delegate while dismissing the UIWebView's ViewController. Normally you don't expect something like this, so there might be specific reason why this isn't set to weak by default.

Comment: Good question. Submit a bug report to Apple. https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @rmaddy why do you think it's a bug ? It could be intentional as well.

Comment: Apple changed most of the `assign` delegates to `weak` a while ago. Not sure why `UIWebView` wasn't updated too.

Comment: It does seem like a bug. If it's weak, the pointer changes to nil when the object is deallocated. If it's assign, the pointer points to a now-dead object, possibly causing a zombie. This could cause crashes if you write your code expecting weak pointers to become nil, like you can usually do in ARC.

Comment: @DuncanC exactly and it does crash. I am just trying to understand if there is an edge case in which making it assign is beneficial. I am just curious :)

Comment: I'd file a bug report and see what Apple says like rmaddy suggests. Filing a bug report is more likely to give you an answer than trying to ask Apple in other ways, and it if IS wrong, it will get on their list to fix.

Comment: @DuncanC thanks. Do you have a link to radar ?

Comment: Do a google search on "Apple Bug Reporter", or use https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if the UIWebViewDelegate defined as WEAK then in ARC it will automatically **nil** the reference of delegate. So UIWebViewDelegate marked as ASSIGN because if the class is not compiled with ARC then we have to take care of set it as nil.

Comment: if that's the case they would have have it for all delegates and not just UIWebView.